# Avoiding duplicate keys in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a very simple class generated by Entity Framework (V 6.2) with a property that is also a primary key.

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make sure that when I create a new item (or modify one existing), it prevents me from doing so if the name already exists ?

I know that `MyContext.SaveChanges()` will generate an exception, but is it possible to do it earlier ? Like when you call `MyContext.Products.Add(MyNewProduct)` ? Or when the name is modified ?

I could change the set property in the auto-generated file made by EF, but it will get erased everytime I regenerate the model...

Comment: Are you using CodeFirst or DatabaseFirst approach?

Comment: @Wurd database first else he wouldn't have to regenerate the model

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you are generating the key in code (not db auto int) and your app has a lot of concurrent requests you might run into concurrency issues. For example request A => B => A gets ID => B gets ID => A Saved => B concurrency clash with A on save.

Comment: @Wurd I'm using Database First approach. I won't run into concurrency issues since this soft is designed to be used on one computer at a time only (I'll keep it in mind though in case this changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if (db.Products.Any(p => p.Name == newProduct.Name))
        {
            return "A record with the same name already exists.";
        }
        else
        {
            db.Products.Add(newProduct);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I agree this is your best option. The benefit of using any is that it returns immediately after it finds a match.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think checking uniqueness in the setter or the context.Add() method is a good idea since you can run into performance issues when you add multiple entities at once. Adding the check in the overridden SaveChanges() method is probably a better idea.

You can change the EF code generation template (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/codegen/) to generate the checks for each required entity type based on some [extended property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or some other metadata in the database to something like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var productNames = ChangeTracker.Entries<Products>()
        .Where(x => (x.State == EntityState.Added) || 
            (x.State == EntityState.Modified && x.OriginalValues["Name"] != x.CurrentValues["Name"]))
        .Select(x => x.Entity.Name)
        .ToList();
    if (Products.Any(x => productNames.Contains(x.Name)))
    {
        throw new Exception("Duplicated keys");
    }
    // same goes for other similar entities

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I have checked your link but they apparently try to discourage changing the templates. Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't think they discourage changing the templates in general. My understanding is they just recommend using certain templates as a base for changes over the others